# Hive - split cell into multiple column

Tags: sql, hive, hiveql

I have referred to prior posts to split one column into two. Looks like the examples that I am referring to are sql, which may be different compared to Hive. How do I convert the orig_data below to results data?

```
            orig_data

name        location    code
Andrew M    NY          145-ABG
Paul C      NY          1787-ATG
Kate M      NY          3874-WV

            results

name        location    ID      per
Andrew M    NY          145     ABG
Paul C      NY          1787    ATG
Kate M      NY          3874    WV

select 
  name, location,
  left(code, charindex('-',code) as id, --not working
  right(code, charindex('-',code) as per, --not working
from 
  orig_table;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `substr` and `instr`

```
select 
name, location,
substr(code, 1, instr(code,'-')-1) as id, 
substr(code, instr(code,'-')+1) as per
from orig_table;
```

Comment: after removing len(code) it started to work from line 4... Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

here is an example:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE bdp.optrans_tbl
SELECT
CONCTNS.splitted_cnctns[0] AS con1,
CONCTNS.splitted_cnctns[1] AS con2,
CONCTNS.splitted_cnctns[2] AS con3
FROM
(SELECT
split(connections,',') AS splitted_cnctns FROM bdp.transact_tbl)CONCTNS;
```

To know more, please see http://bigdataprogrammers.com/split-one-column-into-multiple-columns-in-hive/